# How to have sourcemaps include all my LESS files with gulp

Tags: less, gulp, gulp-less, gulp-sourcemaps

I have two LESS files in my /less folder :

main.less:

```
@import 'vars';

body{
  background-color: @blau;
}
```

and vars.less

```
@blau : #6621ab;
```

My gulp task using gulp-less and gulp-sourcemaps

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('./less/main.less')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```

CSS generation (at /public/main.css) works fine, but in sourcemaps, i can only see main.less, not vars.less . Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i understand your configuration generate the following sourcemap code:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIm1haW4ubGVzcyJdLCJuYW1lcyI6W10sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiQUFFQTtFQUNFLHlCQUFBIiwiZmlsZSI6Im1haW4uY3NzIiwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsiQGltcG9ydCAndmFycyc7XG5cbmJvZHl7XG4gIGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IEBibGF1O1xufVxuIl0sInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIvc291cmNlLyJ9 */
```

The encoded version:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["main.less"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAEA;EACE,yBAAA","file":"main.css","sourcesContent":["@import 'vars';\n\nbody{\n  background-color: @blau;\n}\n"],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

Your `vars.less` does not generate any output to the CSS and so should not included in the sourcemap.

As soon as your `vars.less` generates output, for instance add `.selector {p:1;}` at the end of this file, the file will also be included in the source map:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["vars.less","main.less"],"names":[],"mappings":"AACA;EAAW,IAAA;;ACCX;EACE,yBAAA","file":"main.css","sourcesContent":["@blau : #6621ab;\n.selector {p:1;}\n","@import 'vars';\n\nbody{\n  background-color: @blau;\n}\n"],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

Notice that the lessc compiler has different option for source maps:

```
  --source-map[=FILENAME]  Outputs a v3 sourcemap to the filename (or output filename.map)
  --source-map-rootpath=X  adds this path onto the sourcemap filename and less file paths
  --source-map-basepath=X  Sets sourcemap base path, defaults to current working directory.
  --source-map-less-inline puts the less files into the map instead of referencing them
  --source-map-map-inline  puts the map (and any less files) into the output css file
  --source-map-url=URL     the complete url and filename put in the less file
```

The gulp-sourcemaps outputs the same result as compiling with both the `--source-map-less-inline` and `--source-map-map-inline` options

Comment: Hi Bass!! By replacing `gulp.src('./less/main.less')` with `gulp.src('./less/*.less')` its generating vars.css file, with it's own sourcemapping. Then, including vars.css into my html, i can see it's source :D Dou you know any technique to include vars.less sourcemapping into main.css, so i just have to include one file? Thanks for your time!